# BigQery: bytes comparison

Tags: database, google-bigquery, byte, dataformat

I am working in BigQuery with a data import from a MySQL db.
The unique identifiers of the data are in bytes-format. After joining via the identifier,
I noticed that BigQuery matches IDs that are not the same (at least from my understanding). Example:
1ypmHnQZQmS14JSDyRD9TQ== and tCZG94FdQYinmdULHGUjZg==
When I run

```
select TO_BASE64(b'tCZG94FdQYinmdULHGUjZg==') != TO_BASE64(b'tCZG94FdQYinmdULHGUjZg==')
```

It returns `true`.
But I dont know how to make this work in the join condition, as I can't parse the b prefix in this case